# Equip the additive group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology. What is its Pontryagin Dual?

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-analysis

Just like the title says, what is the Pontryagin Dual of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, when we equip it with the discrete topology? In particular, since this dual must be compact, what is the formula for its Haar probability measure (in terms of tensor products of p-adic measures or what-have-you), and, what is the formula for the duality pairing—that is, the bilinear map $f:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\times\widehat{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, so that every character on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $x\mapsto e^{2\pi if\left(x,\xi\right)}$ for some $\xi\in\widehat{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}$?

Answer (score 1):

As a discrete group, $G=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\times H$ where $H$ is a huge coproduct of copies of $\mathbb Q$. The dual of the first factor is $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$, the product of all the various $p$-adic integers (for all $p$) $\mathbb Z_p$. This has a familiar Haar measure, etc. Since $\mathbb Q$ is an ascending union (colimit) of ${1\over N}\mathbb Z$'s, its dual is the limit of the duals of those limitands, namely, a limit of larger-and-larger circles, so is $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$, where $\mathbb A$ is the rational adeles. Each of these has its usual (quotient) Haar measure.

Comment: I'm intimately familiar with the dual of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. The trouble is with $H$. If I recall correctly, doesn't the existence of $H$ require the axiom of choice? Equally important: I have no clue as to how to formulate the duality bracket for $H$.

Comment: @MCS, yes, at least superficially, the big group $H$ does not have a very explicit/concrete description. I do not know any "formula" for the isomorphism, obviously. So then I doubt that we can write a "formula" for the pairing, either. But this is just a superficial appraisal. But/and if you allow me the isomorphism to that big product of $\mathbb Q$'s and duals $\mathbb A/\mathbb Q$'s, I might be able to write the pairing...

Comment: @paulgarrett Could you please expand on how the limit of larger-and-larger circles involves $\Bbb A$?

Comment: $\Bbb{R/Z} \cong (\Bbb{R/Z})_{tors} \times( \Bbb{R/Z}) /(\Bbb{R/Z})_{tors}$ where $\Bbb{R/Z}_{tors}=\Bbb{Q/Z}$ and $( \Bbb{R/Z}) /(\Bbb{R/Z})_{tors}$ is torsion free abelian whose multiplication by $n$ is an isomorphism thus it is a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, with axiom of choice it has a basis making it $\cong \Bbb{Q}^\mathfrak{c}$, since we are with discrete topology any real sequence should be in  its  dual

Comment: @LukasKofler, ah, yes, this is a charming story of how the adeles are already present in nature, rather than "being defined". The case of $\mathbb R/p^n\mathbb Z$ already illustrates the point, since the limit is $(\mathbb R\times \mathbb Q_p)/\mathbb Z[{1\over p}]$. That example is more tractable (I think goes back to Eilenberg-MacLane c. 1942.) These are "solenoids". A fuller discussion is in some of my course notes at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/, findable by looking for keyword "solenoids".

Comment: @paulgarrett Fascinating! Thank you.

Comment: @LukasKofler Happy to entertain! :)